# Angular table <tr mat-header-row> not working

Tags: angular, angular-material

Im currently using Angular material @7.x and code below causes an error like below.

> Error: Missing definitions for header, footer, and row; cannot
>   determine which columns should be rendered.

```
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
```

I found the alternative solution like below but not applying the correct css.

Code below is working but not creating a `tr` which causes broken table.

```
  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
```

[image]

Comment: Are they imported in ng module.?

Comment: Yes I have done this
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
Can it look similar even if module wasn't imported like the attached table image?

Comment: You mention the import line, but it also needs to be imported for the module / exported.